# textView gets cutoff vertically when put into ListView. Cannot expand to fill multiple lines

Tags: android, listview, textview

I've searched for quite a while trying to find the solution to this problem and have had no luck. The best way to describe this is with a visual:

[image: Cutoff TextView]

What is one way that one could expand the textView when the user inputs something than is more that one line?

sorry, this is what my xml looks like for the listitem:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bDelete"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bDelete"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bDelete"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bDelete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="DONE" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what the xml looks like for the mainscreen (the one in the picture):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/artport">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

<Button
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bAdd"
    android:contentDescription="@string/addItemContentDescription"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/addItemHint" />

</RelativeLayout>   


<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bClearedList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:text="View Deleted Items" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does your list item layout look like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your xml in the TextView use this attribute, this will provide you extendable text view allowing the textView to go down as user put something in

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

Comment: unfortunately  the textView is still cutoff. I have also followed another users suggestion of wrap_content...and that too does not change the output

Comment: the problem was that I had it align with the button to the right. But I got now so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the layout of list item in the attribute

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```